# Table filtering with pipes using ngfor and web api data

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to make a filter for my table so that when I search by a parameter it only shows the row containing the parameter. Here's a working example of what I'm trying to achieve - [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/l1oTNT/).

I used the code from that plunkr and [this website](https://octoperf.com/blog/2016/04/05/angular2-ngfor-filter-using-pipes/) as reference and tried implementing it in my solution. I get the table data from web api.

I'm trying to filter by "codeListVesselID".
Here is the code:

**vesel.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CodeListVessel } from './vessels.component';

@Pipe({
    name: 'vesselfilter',
    pure: false
})
@Injectable()
export class VesselIDFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(vessel: CodeListVessel[], args: any[]): any {
    return vessel.filter(CodeListVessel => CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

The pipe is defined in app.module.ts under declarations.

**vessels.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
...
import { VesselIDFilter } from '../vessels/vessels.pipe';

@Component({
    selector: 'vessels',
    template: require('./vessels.component.html'),
    styleUrls: ['./vessel.component.css']
})

export class vesselsComponent {
    // to get the Vessel Details  
    public vessel: CodeListVessel[] = [];
    ...

    constructor(public http: Http, private dialogService: DialogService, private confirmationService: ConfirmationService, private auth: Auth) {
        this.getData();
    }
    //to get all the Vessel data from Web API  
    getData() {
        this.http.get('/api/CodeListVesselAPI/Vessel').subscribe(result => {
        this.vessel = result.json();
        });
    }
    ...
}

export interface CodeListVessel {
    codeListVesselID: string;
    mmsi: string;
    imo: number;
    ...
}
```

**vessels.component.html**

```html
<input type="text" id="inputID" class="form-control" placeholder="Code" [(ngModel)]="codeListVesselID">
<div class="container">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <table >
                <tr>
                    <th width="100">Code</th>
                    <th width="160">MMSI</th>
                    <th width="160">IMO</th>
                    ...
                </tr>
            <tbody *ngFor="let CodeListVessel of vessel | vesselfilter:codeListVesselID;">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:black">{{CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:black">{{CodeListVessel.mmsi}}</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span style="color:black">{{CodeListVessel.imo}}</span>
                    </td>
                    ...
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the error I get for running the above code: 
[image: Pic]
It points to the code in pipe but I don't know what the problem is.
If I remove the filter code the data shows properly in the table so the data gets through fine.

There may also be an issue in another part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export class VesselIDFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(vessel: CodeListVessel[], args: any[]): any {
    return vessel.filter(CodeListVessel => CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

In your pipe `args` is not going to be an array. You are actually receiving the id for the vessel that you want to filter on as the second argument. There are 2 things you can do.

#### Solution 1

You can change type the argument to what it actually is, which is a string:

```
export class VesselIDFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(vessel: CodeListVessel[], vesselId: string): any {
    if (!vesselId || vesselId === '') {
      return vessel;
    }

    return vessel.filter(CodeListVessel => CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID.toLowerCase().indexOf(vesselId.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

#### Solution 2

Or you can change the type to a proper rest argument:

```
export class VesselIDFilter implements PipeTransform {
  transform(vessel: CodeListVessel[], ...args: any[]): any {
    return vessel.filter(CodeListVessel => CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }
}
```

Make sure that if no filter is selected that you are actually implementing the desired behaviour. Do you want to show all items if no filter is selected or hide all items. This is up to you.

See plunker for working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/z8OwlH0JwfXe2qCLRP5B?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comment above. Trying your solution 1 resulted in the following error: "Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined". Would it be possible to modify @Amit 's answer to make it work properly or is another approach necessary?

Comment: I want to show all items if no filter is selected. What argument should be used in this case?

Comment: Can you check the first solution again? You have to check whether the filter value is actually a string containing something, if not you return the whole array. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your updated solution 1 works! Thank you very much for your cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

I think `codeListVesselID` is maybe undefined during page init and thus args is empty and cannot access [0].

Try changing your transform function to this one:

```
transform(vessel: CodeListVessel[], args: any[]): any {
    if (args && args.length) {
        return vessel.filter(CodeListVessel => CodeListVessel.codeListVesselID.toLowerCase().indexOf(args[0].toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
    else {
        return vessel;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked but I'm having a small issue with it though.

Comment: If I search a lowercase example it works as intended, but if I search for an uppercase example it shows a row and the one below it. Picture:
http://imgur.com/a/TBSDQ. Same result if I search for "ACHA". Any ideas? If not I'll still mark your answer as a correct one.

Comment: This is happening because you are grabbing the first character of the string and comparing it. This means that anything with the character `a` will be shown if your search starts with `a`. Check my answer for more clarity.